# Price History for each item in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have this table

```
Transactions
- id
- user_id // this will point to which user did this transaction
- item_id // this will point to which item in this transaction
- date
```

```
Products
- id
- name
```

```
Items
- id
- product_id // this will point to which product this item is
- name
- price
```

The problem is, overtime, the item's price will change. 
To prevent changes in the old transaction history's price 
I need a way to keep old item's price.

How can I make the right database design to solve this?

Comment: Maybe just save price to the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this info on the Transaction:

```
Transaction
 - id
 - user_id
 - item_id
 - item_price
 - any_other_transaction_specific_info
```

This also lets you apply discounts or any other modifications on the actual price for each transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to save price current product price when transaction is done in transaction table with a price column.

```
Transactions
- id
- user_id // this will point to which user did this transaction
- item_id // this will point to which item in this transaction
- date
- price
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define a `date` for each transaction record. on the other hand, you can have another table for recording the product price `priceLogs.(like: product_id, price and date)`. anytime a product's price is changed, a record is added to the table. this will also help you in some more business issues for tracking the price of products.

you need to query the price of each product based on the date of transactions. This might make you write a bit of joins in your query.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should instead create another table as Item_Pricing and this should help you finalize the pricing history. The table Item_Pricing history should be like this Item_Pricing(id[PK], itm_id[FK], price, **price_still_in_use**, date_price_created,...). The idea is that the colum **price_still_in_use** should be considered as a flag that can have value 1(yes) or 0(no). Then in your table **transaction** this is the price that should be considered. Then each transaction or sale should relate to the pricing that still in use as followed :

Transactions
(id[PK],...,**item_pricing_id[FK] // this will point to Item_Pricing(item_pricing_id)**, quantity, date)

So if the item price changes in your application the price of the item should no longer be available if no longer used. A trigger might also help you for best results so that the same item can't have more than one price that has the value yes for the column(attribute) **price_still_in_use**